# How do I make an animation made with ImageMagick play on my python Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, imagemagick

I'm new to animations on Python, so I'm studying how to make one. So far, I copied the code from [DevelopPaper](https://developpaper.com/using-matplotlib-library-to-generate-animation-charts/) but when I run the cells, it only shows a static image of it. I also tried it for other animation examples there but it's the same for all of them -- animations from Imagemagick won't play on Jupyter Notebook but when I open the saved file manually it works just fine. How do I get the animations to play on Jupyter Notebook itself? Thanks!

[image: Here's how it looks like on my Jupyter Notebook.]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 4), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

anim.save('sine_wave.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the examples from ["Embedding animation into Jupyter Notebook"](https://www.numfys.net/howto/animations/) (bottom of the page)?

Comment: @emcconville i tried importing the code from the site you mentioned but it refers to data from a code they posted on another page which is no longer available. I'll try using the data from the code from DevelopPaper, and will just see how it goes. Thanks!